# How to set the timer in shell

Tags: shell, sh

Can we set the timer in shell script?
means if I set the timer for 20 secs my shell scripts should be execute like this :

```
20..19..18..17..
```

after completing the I should get the result. Is it possible ? Please assist me.

Comment: what shell? what OS?  but assuming *Nix  `man sleep`  and just put `sleep 20` at the top of your scripts ? Or do you want it to run for 20 seconds?

Comment: Hi Doon,
I want my .sh file to be execute in 20 secs. And after executing ./xyz.sh file it should show the time execution :

20..19..18..17..

Comment: Do you want to interrupt the process if it is not finished in 20 seconds?

Comment: yes correct Doon . Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want: if `xyz.sh` finishes in 3 seconds, do you want to wait an additional 17 seconds?  Or do you want to interrupt xyz.sh after 20 seconds and make it produce output?  If the latter:

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash 

./xyz.sh &

i=${1-20}
echo
while test $i -gt 0; do printf "\r$((i--))..."; sleep 1; done
kill $!


$ cat xyz.sh 
#!/bin/sh

foo() { echo "this program doesn't do much"; }
trap foo TERM
sleep 30 &
wait
```

Comment: Thanks William. I got the logic from your code. I want my script to be waiting for given timing. If its taking more than given time I would like to interrupt the process.

Answer (score 0):

With for loop it looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=20; i>0; i-- ))
do
clear
echo -n "$i"
sleep 1
done
```